# Как получить первую попавшуюся картинку в посте группы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

*Попытался сделать так:*

```py
import requests


token = 'secret_tocken'
b = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-98210264&access_token='+str(token)+'&count=2&v=5.95')

print(b.text)
```

На выходе получил огромный текст, в котором куча разных ссылок: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/u7HctByA)

***Собственно вопрос:***

> Как мне получить самую последнюю ссылку на картинку, при этом
>   учитывая, что ссылка будет меняться?

Может есть другие способы? Я пытался использовать `vk_api` на `Python`'e, но не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from vk_api import VkApi


vkSession = VkApi(login='...', password='...')  # Or access_token authorization
vkSession.auth()                                # Or access_token authorization
vk = vkSession.get_api()


def main():
    posts = vk.wall.get(owner_id=-98210264, count=2)['items']

    for post in posts:
        atchs = post.get('attachments')

        if atchs:
            for atch in atchs:
                if atch['type'] == 'photo':
                    photo = atch['photo']

                    url = photo['sizes'][-1]['url']
                    print(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Код частично рабочий.Выдаёт запрос на одну и туже картинку.

Comment: @1xev3 Спасибо за замечание, я опечатался и пропустил минус перед `id` группы. Я поправил это. Проверьте, пожалуйста, ещё раз.

Comment: Да,спасибо большое.Работает.